# Как проверить, существует ли файл?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Как проверить перед считыванием, существует ли файл или ещё нет?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Check if a file exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13980871) от участника [@eSS92](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1819719/ess92)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/13980871

Answer (score 3):

1. Используя `BFILE` и функцию `fileexists` пакета `dbms_lob`:

   ```
   create or replace function fileExists (dirName varchar2, fileName varchar2) return char is
       fileloc bfile;
   begin
       fileloc := bfilename (upper(dirName), fileName);
       return case dbms_lob.fileexists (fileloc) when 1 then 'y' else 'n' end;  
   end;
   /
   ```
2. Используя функцию `fgetattr` пакета `utl_file`:

   ```
   create or replace function fileExists (dirName varchar2, fileName varchar2) return char is
       fexists boolean;
       flen   number;
       fsize  number;
   begin
       utl_file.fgetattr (upper (dirName), fileName, fexists, flen, fsize);
       return case when fexists then 'y' else 'n' end;
   end;
   /
   ```

Проверить и получить результат:

```
select fileExists ('tempdir', 'data.csv') fileExists from dual
/
FILEEXISTS
----------
y
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13985055) от участника [@Nick Krasnov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997660/nick-krasnov)</sub>